# Generar tablero de botones por codigo en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

estoy trabajando en una aplicacion en android y necesito crear un tablero (hecho de botones).

Yo ya genero el tablero desde el codigo de mi clase java, pero el problema es que los botones se salen de la vista (se salen de la pantalla). Ya he intentado varias cosas con los LayoutParams pero nada me ha funcionado. Espero que me puedan ayudar gracias.

Aqui el codigo que genera el tablero (los botones)

```
    botones = new Button[numLetras];

    for (int i = 0; i < numLetras; i++ )
    {
        botones[i] = new Button(layout.getContext());
        botones[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        botones[i].setText(texto[i]);
        botones[i].setId(i + 1 );
        layout.addView(botones[i]);

    }
```

y aqui una foto de como queda.(El texto que tiene que aparecer es "TEXTOEJEMPLO")

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Adelmo, nos explicas que se sale de la vista, pero falta que expliques como esperas que se vea, ya que puede hacerse de diferentes formas (achicar los botones para ajustar el ancho, poner una segunda linea de botones, etc). Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que ponerle el **Weight**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);

    botones[i].setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Si lo que quieres es tenerlo en una sola linea puedes hacer esto. así debería salir **TEXTOEJEMPLO** en una sola linea.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono correcto..

Answer (score 0):

Quiza te sirva intentar con un **GridView**. Un **GridView** es un **ViewGroup** que muestra los elementos en una rejilla de dos dimensiones, desplazable. Los elementos de la cuadrícula se insertan automáticamente según la disposición usando un **ListAdapter**.

[Más información.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede decirse que es relativamente sencillo, los botones(o vistas) se distribuirán uniformemente si les asignamos un peso de 1

```
    //Obtiene instancia de contenedor padre
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    //Definimos un texto en base al cual se crearan los botones.
    String s = "TEXTOEJEMPLO";
    String[] letras = s.split("");;//Convierte texto a arreglo Char

    int cantidadBotones = s.length(); //Obtenemos la cantidad de  botones a dibujar.
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidadBotones; i++) {
        Button bn = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        bn.setId(1 + 2000); //Define ids
        bn.setMinHeight(0);
        bn.setMinimumHeight(0);
        bn.setPadding(0,0,0,0); //Elimina padding
        bn.setTextSize(14);
        bn.setText(letras[i+1]); //Asigna letra.
        //Crea contenedor con peso de 1 para cada elemento.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
        bn.setLayoutParams(params);
        //Agrega vista a contenedor padre.
        container.addView(bn);
    }
```

de esta forma podemos agregar los botones con el mismo peso y se distribuiran uniformemente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]